# Force MacBook to install updates when it restarts

Tags: macos, software-update, reminders

I kept getting an annoying notification alert "Some updates could not be installed, Restart / Remind me."

I kept hitting "remind me tomorrow" until a couple nights ago. Since then I have restarted my computer twice but the alert keeps appearing.

It looks like the updates won't be installed without initiating the restart through that prompt.

How can I restart *and*  update my laptop at a time that is convenient to me? (Not when the prompt nags me to do so, I want that off my screen fast).

Comment: On the prompt, you can click an appropriately far-away timeframe and then open System Preferences > Software Update and press install there, which will initiate the restart

Comment: @EzekielElin there seem to be only two options, install in an hour, install tonight, and neither are appropriate for me 99% of the time.

Comment: I believe that, in some cases, you have to actually go into the App Store or Software Update (System Preferences) and **manually** start the update process. This has happened to me a few times.

Comment: @theonlygusti Is there not an Install Later option that doesn't specify a timeframe? You can then manually initiate when you want.

Comment: @EzekielElin I don't know how to manually initiate it (that's what this question is about). When I next have the time I'm going to check the app store.

Comment: @theonlygusti As I said (sorry if it was confusing), the Software Update page in System Preferences has an Install button that will initiate it manually.

Comment: @EzekielElin oh yeah you're right, for some reason I completely misread or didn't read (I don't know how that happened) that part of your comment, sorry. I think that solution will work for me.

Comment: @theonlygusti no worries! glad you figured out something that works